# Zipping a folder in remote location

Tags: java

My application needs to zip a folder in remote location. I am able to zip it in my local system but not able to go ahead with zipping in remote location. Please suggest me how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of access do you have to the remote machine? SSH? NFS? Samba? ...?

Comment: Since it is tagged java, are you trying to do this programmatically?

Comment: Maybe you do not have unzip/zip installed at the server! Many times I had this issue with linux machines, just installed unzip and solved it.

Comment: sorry didn't mention it earlier..its a j2ee application...it has to access folder in remote server and zip it there

Comment: See:  http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html

Comment: Java file class accepts UNC paths i.e. new File("\\\\server\\folder\\folder\\"). That is if you wish *your* application to perform the zipping.

Answer (score 0):

Careful with remote file paths. Depending on the protocol you're using to attempt to access the remote file path, you might need to double-escape back slashes. For example, just recently, I wrote a program to create zips over windows unc paths. I had to enter the paths to the remote zip file in my properties file like so:

```
\\\\remote-host\\shared-dir\\foo\\bar\\blah.zip
```